# What is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{2^{\sqrt{n}}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the value of

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{2^{\sqrt{n}}}$$

It's clearly convergent but is it possible to calculate the sum?

Comment: There is no reason to think there is a closed-form expression for this sum.

Comment: Why not? How can one tell? I guess it's equivalent with $\sum x^{\sqrt{n}}$ not having a closed form - but how is it proven?

Comment: Is't $\tt\mbox{clearly convergent}$ ?.

Comment: It is just a matter of mathematical intuition. If the terms in a sequence involve higher functions, it is unlikely that a closed-form expression for the sum exists. There is no proof. And to seek such a proof would be very time-consuming.

Comment: @FelixMarin My reasoning is that $2^x$ is eventually larger than any polynomial in $x$, for instance $x^6$. So for $n > N$, $2^{\sqrt{n}} > n^3$.

Comment: Yes, it is clearly convergent.

Comment: In fact, there are essentially no proofs on "this number has no closed form".  (Unlike "this function has no closed form".) But, in fact, *almost every* numerical series you write down at random has no closed form...

Comment: Could L'Hôpital's rule be applied? It is infinity over infinity. ALso, according to wolfram alpha "lim x->infinity sum (x/(2^sqrt(x)))" returns $51.919191....$

Comment: well maybe forget L'Hôpital

Comment: @GEdgar can you prove that? :-P

Comment: @M.Wind I read $\Large 2^{n/\,\sqrt{\, n\,}\,}$. Sorry.

Comment: @FelixMarin well $2^{\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}}} = 2^{\sqrt{n}}$ anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sum is not known to possess a closed form expression. In general, no series of the form $\displaystyle\sum_{n}a^{\large n^b}$ does, for $a\neq0$ and $b\not\in\{0,1,2\}$. However, $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty n~a^{\sqrt n}~\simeq~\int_0^\infty x~a^{\sqrt x}~dx$, which, after letting $x=t^2$, can be evaluated using the expression of the  [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), yielding $~\dfrac{12}{\ln^4a}$

Comment: That's is the [Abel-Plana formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel–Plana_formula) first term.