# How to calculate the sum of the infinite series $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{n}{2^\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do you calculate the sum of an infinite series like

$$ \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{n}{2^\sqrt{n}}$$

//EDIT

//Ignore

I searched up how to find this with infinite geometric series solution which was

$$\frac{a}{1-r}$$

$a$ being first value and $r$ being common ratio.
But I could not find common ratio.

**Please give me common ratio of this series.**

//Ignore

I have also tried limits like

$$ \lim_{a \to \infty} \sum_{n = 0}^a \frac{n}{2^\sqrt{n}} $$

but they don't actually give me a solid answer.

**Correction**

Prove this infinite series is convergent.

Comment: This is not a geometric series. That is why you could not find $r$.

Comment: How do you find the sum then?

Comment: It's not evident that there should be any closed form for this sum; where does it come from?

Comment: I got this from a Math.SE question that I couldn't solve at all.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1066475/what-is-sum-n-1-infty-fracn2-sqrtn/1066552#1066552 is the question link.

Comment: @Bot Er, what exactly is your goal in posting a new question, when you found the question here? This question isn't any more likely to get an answer than the original one you link to.

Comment: I wrote my answer before seeing the link to the duplicate :(

Comment: I thought that I could solve this with geometric infinite series but I couldn't =(

Comment: If the OP is interested in calculating (numerically) rather than estimating the value of the series, the one answer to the "duplicate" question is not going to be of any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you will be hard-pressed to find a closed form for the sum,
you can use the comparison test to show that it converges. Numerical
computation shows that the value is approximately
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^{\sqrt{n}}}\approx51.919095230880139.
$$
You can get pretty good closed-form estimates for this by integrating
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^{\sqrt{n}}}\approx\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^{\sqrt{n}}}dn=\frac{12}{\left(\log\left(2\right)\right)^{4}}\approx51.985162021107868.
$$
If you require accurate results, just use numerical computation.

For example, in MATLAB:

```
nmax = 1e+12;
tol  = 1e-16;

t = 0;
for n = 1:nmax
    m = n/2^sqrt(n);
    t = t + m;
    if m < tol
        break
    end
end

disp(t);
```

You can make `tol` smaller to increase accuracy or larger to increase speed of computation.