# For which $x$ does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{\alpha}x^{\sqrt{n}}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to know for which values of $x$ this series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{\alpha}x^{\sqrt{n}}$$ converges with $\alpha \in  \mathbb{R}$$.

This series is defined for $  x 
 \ge 0$.

The necessary condition for the convergence $a_n \sim 0$ is satified for $0 \le x < 1$

and now I'm trying to apply some criteria for the convergence and either the

root criterion or the ratio one are inconclusive.

Can you suggest something to solve the exercize?

Comment: possible hint in this post by comparison with an integral and use of Gamma function https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1066701/399263

Comment: Show that for $x \in [0,1)$ and any $\alpha,$ $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{\alpha} x^{\sqrt{n}} = 0.$ This tells you that for every $\alpha, x$ there is some $n_0(\alpha, x)$ such that for $n \ge n_0,$ the terms in the series are dominated by $n^{-2}$. This is enough to establish convergence.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

For $ x>0,$ The general term is

$$u_n=e^{\sqrt{n}\Bigl(\frac{\alpha \ln(n)}{\sqrt{n}}+\ln(x)\Bigr)}$$
If $x>1$, its limit is not zero, thus the series diverges.

If $ x=1$, the series is a Riemann one which converges only if $ -\alpha>1$.

If $ x<1$,
the series converges because

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}n^2u_n=0$$

(For $ n$ great enough $0<n^2u_n<1$ and the comparison test ).
instead of $n^2$ , you can take $n^{\beta}$ for any $\beta>1$.

Comment: Is it Ok, or you need some addition.

Comment: I don't understand why you wrote $n^2$ in the Last passage

Comment: What is the criterion that you used? So far I used the classic criteria such as the root one, the ratio criterion but i have used the limit of $a_n$ only for the necessary condition of convergence

Comment: @Anne I just added two lines to explain why.

Comment: I don't understand why you put $n^2 u_n$ , what does represent this quantity, is there same criterion that i didn't study that says all depends on this $n^2 u_n$?

Comment: @Anne You cane replace $2$ by any $\beta>1$ and use the fact that $u_n<\frac{1}{n^\beta}$

Comment: yes, but the point is  why do you put $n^{\beta}$ if there isn't this term in the exercize?

Comment: Have a look at what we call Bertrand series and you will understand this criteria, also called the limit comparison test.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\alpha >0.$ Then clearly the series diverges for $x\ge 1,$ simply because the $n$th term doesn't tend to $0.$

Staying with $\alpha >0,$  let $0\le x <1.$ Let's group terms:

$$\tag 1 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^\alpha x^{\sqrt n} = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=m^2}^{(m+1)^2-1}n^\alpha x^{\sqrt n}.$$

In the inside sum there are $2m$ terms, each of which is bounded above by $[(m+1)^2]^\alpha x^m.$ Therefore $(1)$ is bounded above by

$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}2m[(m+1)^2]^\alpha x^m.$$

This series converges because we have polynomial growth in $m$ vs. exponential decay in $x^m.$ If I seem to be hand-waving, use the ratio test to see this.

I'll leave $\alpha \le 0$ to you for now.